# How do I get the name of a referenced Project or Library?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently developing a plugin for Eclipse that analyzes dependencies and references of Java and plugin projects in the Workspace.

However I cannot for the life of me find a way to get the name of a referenced project or library found in the Classpath Entries.

Here's what I have (excerpt from a longer method):

```
IJavaProject j= JavaCore.create(project);          //project is an IProject
try {
    IClasspathEntry[] classpath= j.getRawClasspath();

    // Get required Libraries and Projects
    for (IClasspathEntry entry : classpath) {
        switch (entry.getEntryKind()) {
        case IClasspathEntry.CPE_LIBRARY: {
            //Retrieve name of the Library
            break;              
            }
        case IClasspathEntry.CPE_PROJECT: {
            //Retrieve name of the Project
            break;
        }
    }
} catch [...]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get the names at the marked positions, or a better way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with someone else, I have finally found the solution:

```
switch (entry.getEntryKind()) {
    case IClasspathEntry.CPE_LIBRARY: {
        String name = entry.getPath().segment(0);
        /* Further processing for a Library
        *...
        */
        break;              
        }
    case IClasspathEntry.CPE_PROJECT: {
        String name = entry.getPath().segment(0);
        /* Further processing for a Project
        *...
        */
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Did you intend for the body of each case block to be the same? If not, could you fix it? If so, then the entire switch statement is unnecessary.

Comment: Edited with comments. Libraries and Projects are processed differently, but the exact processing added nothing to the question and would have only made it unnecessarily complicated.